# Laravel Update Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Laravel newbie here, I want to create an update route in Laravel, without the resource controller. 
I have the route for the editing

```
Route::get('/indexedit','PagesController@indexedit')->middleware('user');
```

And in there, there is a form with the following

```
<form class="col s12" method="POST" action="indexedit/{{ $val->id }}" >
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

There are two input fields and a button for submiting. I created a route for the update which is

```
Route::post('indexedit/{$id}', 'PagesController@update');
```

But when I submit, it says Route not found. NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: Route::any('/indexedit/{id}', 'PagesController@update'); try it..

Comment: Just tried, returns the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you don't need $ sign in your route ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters)):

```
Route::post('indexedit/{id}', 'PagesController@update');
```

Second of all, I would wrap action url in url() method just in case:

```
<form class="col s12" method="POST" action="{{ url('indexedit/ ' . $val->id }}" >
```

Comment: The mistake was the $ sign in the route, but I will also use the url() method.

Comment: Yeah I know, but IMHO it's good practice to wrap all urls in this method:)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `put` from update rote, not `post`.

This not ok:

```
Route::post('indexedit/{id}', 'PagesController@update');
```

use this:

```
Route::put('indexedit/{id}', 'PagesController@update');
```

Comment: Why should you use put not post for update? I'm learning Laravel and am unsure of the reasoning.